# function undefined reference c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, directx

I have a problem :

FPSlimiter.cpp :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include "FPSlimit.h"

FPSlimiter limiter;

void LIMIT_FPS(DWORD FPS_LIMIT)
{
static DWORD LAST_FRAME_TIME = 0;
limiter.CURRENT_FRAME_TIME = timeGetTime();
if ((limiter.CURRENT_FRAME_TIME - LAST_FRAME_TIME) < (1000 / FPS_LIMIT))
{
    return;
}
LAST_FRAME_TIME = limiter.CURRENT_FRAME_TIME;
}
```

FPSlimiter.h :

```
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <windows.h>

class FPSlimiter
{
    public:
    void LIMIT_FPS(DWORD FPS_LIMIT);
    DWORD CURRENT_FRAME_TIME;
};
```

calling function from main.cpp :

```
DWORD MAX_FPS = 60;
limiter.LIMIT_FPS(MAX_FPS);
```

And i get error :

undefined reference to `FPSlimiter::LIMIT_FPS(unsigned long)'

Sorry for this bunch of code, but i can't find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: add `FPSLimiter::` before `LIMIT_FPS` in FPSLimiter.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT_FPS` is a member of `FPSlimiter`, so your definition has to be in the class' scope:

```
void FPSlimiter::LIMIT_FPS(DWORD FPS_LIMIT) { .... }
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise you are just definint a different, non-member function.